# FullCalendar Title displaying MM/YYYY stacked rather than side by side

Tags: html, css

So, my full calendar title is displaying the title in a stacked manner, rather than side by side: [image]

I would like for the month and year to be alongside eachother. I have tried changing some of the CSS, but I am still relatively new to CSS, so I am probably just missing something. I am using their css file to edit the appearance. How can I fix this?

Edit: not sure if it messes things up, but I am using the Google Calendar API to fill in events. Also, here is the code for my rendering:

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
      var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {  
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        headerToolbar: {
          left: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'today prev,next'
        },
        views: {
          dayGridMonth: {
            titleFormat: { month: 'long', year: 'numeric'}
          }
        },
        googleCalendarApiKey: 'apikeyinputhere',
        eventSources: [
          {
            googleCalendarId: 'email@email.com'
          }
        ]
      });

      calendar.render();
    });

  </script>
```

And here is the CSS I think that renders the title:

```
.fc-direction-ltr .fc-button-group > .fc-button:not(:last-child) {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  }
.fc-direction-rtl .fc-button-group > .fc-button:not(:first-child) {
    margin-right: -1px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  }
.fc-direction-rtl .fc-button-group > .fc-button:not(:last-child) {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  }
.fc .fc-toolbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
  }
.fc .fc-toolbar.fc-header-toolbar {
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  }
.fc .fc-toolbar.fc-footer-toolbar {
    margin-top: 1.5em;
  }
.fc .fc-toolbar-title {
    font-size: 1.75em;
    margin: 0;
    background: rgba(169,169,169,0.01);
    color: #202436;
    
  }
.fc-direction-ltr .fc-toolbar > * > :not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: .75em; /* space between */
  }
.fc-direction-rtl .fc-toolbar > * > :not(:first-child) {
    margin-right: .75em; /* space between */
  }
.fc-direction-rtl .fc-toolbar-ltr { /* when the toolbar-chunk positioning system is explicitly left-to-right */
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
  }
.fc .fc-scroller {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    position: relative; /* for abs-positioned elements within */
  }
.fc .fc-scroller-liquid {
    height: 100%;
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: Please share the HTML that renders the title, and the CSS for that as well.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas the titleFormat: line renders the title